# C:/xampp/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters - XAMPP/Windows

Tags: windows, .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp

I installed XAMPP on my Windows PC.
I created a simple static pages and created .htaccess file in c:\xampp\htdocs.

.htaccess file content is:

**RewriteEngine On**

**RewriteRule ^about-us$ about-us.php [L]**

I am getting 404 for the below page:
**http://localhost/mysite/about-us/**

Anyone help me to identify whats wrong with the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I moved my .htaccess file from htdocs to htdocs/mysite